# SQL*Loader reading a file with missing columns

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I need to create a SQL*Loader control file that can read source files with missing columns. For example, file a:

```
a;b;c
```

And file b:

```
a;b
```

My control file looks like this:

```
load data
APPEND 
into table table_of_parameter
fields terminated by ";" optionally enclosed by '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
    parameters1,
    parameters2,
    parameters3
)
```

And I want this to be the result of loading both files:

```
select * from table_of_parameter

parameters1    parameters2    parameters3
a              b              c
a              b              null (or something else)
```

Is there a way to do this in a control file?

Comment: That's what [`trailing nullcols`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_control_file.htm#SUTIL1121) does... what issues are you having, exactly, when you try this?

Comment: Verified that your control file does exactly what you say you want with those two files. So I don't know what you are really asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this issue..
the problem was that the last paramether is "not Null"
so, if i put a different amount of value, it populare previous parameters that have "default value null" and can't populate this paramether.

Solved moved it before this paramether